# When does Adverbialer Akkusativ require a definite article? Letzte Woche

Tags: article

Why does

> Was hast du letzte Woche gemacht?

Work just as well as

> Was hast du die letzte Woche gemacht?

However

> Was hast du letzten Tag gemacht?

does not work in comparison to

> Was hast du den letzten Tag gemacht?

Going through examples in my head, some sound fine with, some better without. It seems arbitrary to me. Is there a pattern or a certain grammar point behind this?

In Dudenband 4, 8th edition, page 298, paragraph 395, *Gebundener Gebrauch ohne Artikel*, this article-less usage is noted. However there was no reason or pattern given, just examples: Weekdays, week, month, year.

Comment: You must have a different edition of Duden's Grammar book. I have *Duden - Die Grammatik, 10. Auflage (2022).* And there I find on page 298: *4.6 Anredeformen* and *4.7 Kombinationen im linken Außenfeld* as subsections of *4 Metakommunikative Besetzungen im linken Außenfeld* which is a section of the chapter about *gesprochene Sprache.* It is at the end of the first part which deals with sentences. This does not match with your topic. Please tell me the name of the chapter where you found these examples.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Yes, mine is from 2009. The chapter on definite articles.

Comment: "Was hast du letzten Tag gemacht?" does not work because we have the word "gestern". It's equivalent in English: "What did you do last week?" vs "What did you do yesterday?"

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Abschnitt 395, der Satz beginnt mit "Viele feste Wendungen ...", was die Frage schon fast beantwortet.

Comment: @HalvarF: Ich find's nicht. Oran Matheus meint, es wäre im Kapitel über definite Artikel. Das ist in meiner Ausgabe auf Seite 748, hat die Randnummer 1304 und erwähnt mit keiner Silbe den Akkusativ. Wenn du mit »Abschnitt 395« die Randnummer 395 meinst, dann ist die bei mir auf Seite 246 und gehört zum Abschnitt *2.4.2.6 Aufforderung in der indirekten Rede* im Kapitel *Zeit und Geltung* im ersten Teil (*Sätze als Textbausteine*) und auch da werden weder Artikel noch der Akkusativ erwähnt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Oh, ok, ich htte gehofft, dass der Duden wenigstens die Abschnittsnummern/ Randnummern zwischen den Auflagen beibehält. Anscheinend nicht.

Answer (score 1):

The terms *"letzte Woche"* and *"die letzte Woche"* have slightly different meaning.

*"die letzte Woche"* can be a duration of a week until now, from the same day of the week as today or the duration of the last calendar week, depending on the context. It refers to the whole duration, maybe limited to specific hours like working hours or spare time.

I understand

> Was hast du die letzte Woche gemacht?

as "What did you do the whole last week?"

*"letzte Woche"* refers to the last calendar week, not necessarily the whole duration. Depending on the context it can refer to a certain date/time/event *in* the last calendar week.

I understand

> Was hast du letzte Woche gemacht?

as "What did you do at the implied time/event in the last week?"

In theory it would be the same for "Tag", but instead of "letzten Tag" the word "gestern" is used: *"den letzten Tag"* refers to the duration of a day, maybe until now, in contrast to *"gestern"* = at the implied time yesterday.